# fb 'apprequests' redirect to new url or send additional parameter to url

Tags: facebook, apprequests, facebook-app-requests

I need to pass additional parameter to redirect url when the user accept fb app request or need to redirect user to a custom url. How can I do this?...Please see the following code.

```
   $('#sendRequest').click(function() {
          FB.ui(
            {
              method  : 'apprequests',
              message : $(this).attr('data-message')

                    },
            function (response) {
              // If response is null the user canceled the dialog
              if (response != null) {
                 logResponse(response);
              }
            }
          );
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used "data" parameter to send information while sending the request and accessed it in the other end using the "request id".

```
 $('#sendRequest').click(function() {


          FB.ui(
            {
              method  : 'apprequests',
              message : $(this).attr('data-message'),
              data: sessionId,
              max_recipients:1

                    },
            function (response) {
              // If response is null the user canceled the dialog
              if (response != null) {
                 logResponse(response);
              }
            }
          );
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that you can add in the code you’ve shown.

If you need to combine any data with a request, than you’ll have to save this data to your own database, so you can look it up again when receiving the request id(s) send to you when a user accepts requests.